# How to update someone else's charms in the juju charm store

Tags: juju

How do I publish an update to someone else's out of date charm?  I am bringing octave and octave-controller up to date so I can use them.  They are out of date because of changes to apache, and some other things.  I'd like to upgrade the charms in the store which are stagnant and are not shown in the solutions.
Is the process any different from normal publication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit different from normal publication, see this section of the docs:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/latest/authors-charm-store#submitting-a-fix-to-an-existing-charm

It then gets put into a [review queue](http://review.juju.solutions/) and then the fixes get applied to the charm branch.

However the Octave charms are in someone's personal namespaces, so the more correct way to do it is to fork their charms and then update them.

Then (if you want) you can submit your new octave and octave-controller to the charm store to be the default recommended stack. Then in the future those charms are more amenable to be community maintained instead of someone's personal namespace.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.  Now all I have to do is finish making it work :)